# Vagrant global-status all VM's named default

Tags: vagrant

When I run `vagrant global-status`, I get a listing back of all the vagrant managed VM's I'm running, but something I have not expected is output with the machine details. Even though I give every machine an explicit `name` during initialization, the value for `name` in the `global-status` output for every machine is always `default`.

Why does `vagrant status` or `vagrant global-status` not list the actual names of the boxes?  At times, when I've destroyed a box, it has actually destroyed more than one box.

```
id       name    provider   state    directory                           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
e44520d  default virtualbox poweroff /Users/name/code/foo        
1310726  default virtualbox poweroff /Users/name/code/bar    
430fd52  default virtualbox poweroff /Users/name/code/baz
```

The machines are named `foo`, `bar`, `baz`... why are they showing as `default`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have default Vagrantfile as configuration, your machine VM will be named default, so something like

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu-12.04"
  config.vm.hostname = "foo"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  . . .
```

Now, if you have a multi machine configuration, you will have something like this in your Vagrantfile (simplified)

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu-12.04"

  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.hostname = db.test

    db.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |vm|
      vm.vmx["memsize"] = "2048"
    end

    db.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap-dev.sh"
  end

  config.vm.define "app", primary: true do |app|
    app.vm.hostname = app.test
    app.vm.network "private_network", "192.168.50.11"
    app.vm.synced_folder "project/site", "/var/www"
  end
end
```

In this case, you have defined 2 machines `db` and `app` and the `vagrant global-status` will prompt

```
id       name    provider      state       directory
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
de264ac  db      vmware_fusion not running /Volumes/Transcend/Project1
bdd4385  app     vmware_fusion not running /Volumes/Transcend/Project1
```

Comment: I get it... that actually makes sense now why if you only have single VM Vagrantfiles, why they would all be called `default`. Thank you.

Comment: If you change that name, will you have to specify it when using `vagrant ssh` like you do with a multi-host Vagrantfile?

Comment: @Wildcard if you have only 1 VM, no ssh will directly log you in the VM